# Scheduling Discord Python Task

Tags: python, discord

I have read through so many articles, but can't seem to get it.. I have a discord bot and a !news command that works. I'd like to schedule this task to run every 5 minutes. The code below is with it still set as a command, I'm just not sure what to change. Thanks in advance!

```
import all the modules

TOKEN = 'XXX'
description = ...
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
client = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
  
def check(ctx):
    return lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

async def get_input_of_type(func, ctx):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx))
            return func(msg.content)
        except ValueError:
            continue

#other bot commands here, working fine
@bot.command(name='scores', help='starts prompts to retrieve LG league scores')
....

@bot.command(name='news')
async def news(ctx):
   #do stuff here, works fine for coommand
  
keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Have you looked at a python scheduling library or perhaps running an infinite loop with time.sleep

Comment: So I tried using the scheduler library.. something like this.. it works fine when I am just running in a python terminal, but I don't think I'm putting it in the right spot in my bot script.

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(news)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```